# 220 volt GFI triped by hot tub?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a hot tub connected to a 50 amp 220v trip that has a neutral pigtail connected to the neutral bus. The natural for the tub is connected to the bus. The 220v connects directly to the control panel PCB which then has a series of relays to switch the pumps, water heater etc.

The GFCI started tripping. The individual connectors were all separated from the PCB for the 220v connections such that the only thing that was being powered was the control board running 110v. It still tripped the GFCI immediately. The operation of the GFCI felt a bit odd and the ‘on’ position did not feel as though it went home when the power was off.

So I replaced the GFCI with the same result, an instant trip. I then removed the secondary winding's (12v & 24v) from the PCB. Same result. I then removed the ground from the transformer, same result. I then removed the primary coil from power and no trip. I replaced the transformer. When the new transformer is connected I get the exact same problem, instant trip when powered. I then disconnected the hot tub completely at the breaker box. I then wired the new transformer directly to the new GFCI and it trips immediately with no load connected to the secondary.

I tried it by removing the ground from the transformer no change. What am I doing wrong, or is the new transform faulty as well? I just followed the original wiring. When the GFCI is bypassed the tub works as normal. NO I would not use the tub with no GFCI!

---

Follup from OP:

This is a an old installation with a new GFI wired exactly as the old unit had been wired. Just a direct replacement for three wires. Yes being British I use different terminology trip/breaker. You may have hit the nail on the head with the neutral. I just followed the existing wiring verbatim as while this has never been used since I have had the house, it did not enter my head that the original wiring could have been incorrectly installed as it would never have worked. That does not mean to say that the previous occupant did not replace the GFI and quit when the tub did not work. I am not sure that I still have the wiring leaflet it may have been thrown out with the packaging. I dare say that I will be able to locate it on the web. I am used to 240v as a single hot at 50Hz, that does bite!

Thanks, dumb should have looked not copied. The reason why the old one was tripping was due to connecting the neutral to the bus bar not the load on the breaker. Installed correctly and the old breaker and original transformer work fine. I guess the answer is don't assume!

Comment: Is this a new install or a old one that has started failing? I ask this because I am wondering if the gfci breaker was installed correctly.

Comment: Are you using the word "trip" to refer to a circuit breaker?  If so, your first 2 sentences describe your wiring very well, and reveal what we need to solve the problem.  You have wired your GFCI breaker incorrectly.  Read the instructions.  Pay particular attention to what is supposed to happen with the neutral wires.

Comment: Yes, when this tripping start happening?

Comment: @TrevorSams -- can you [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts, so that you can interact fully with your question? In fact, I'll give you an upvote for posting that last paragraph of yours as an answer.